# Registered Joomla site, images folder and files are still accessible

Tags: joomla-3.x

I've made a Registered Joomla site, which means that you have to have a login to access the site itself. I can put articles, menulinks, modules all behind a "Registered", and thus it isn't accessible for public.

My problem however lies in the fact that the attachments of the articles are public accessible, I cannot put them behind a "Registered" to not have it publicly available. How can I fix this? How can I get the images folder to be behind a "Registered" as well?

Comment: Are you worried that google is going to index them? You can always make sure /images is in the robots.txt file, which google honors. The other option is to make an htaccess file for the images folder, but I'm honestly not sure if joomla will bypass that or honor that and lock all images (and ask the user for a password).

Comment: No I've got taken care of that. It's for linking files directly, so that people can dodge the login for the documents.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about files and not images, use something like Docman. It locks it's own folders and hides the path. Only registered users can get access and no outside person can see into those folders. It also has an editor button to help you easily attach files to articles.

[Docman](http://www.joomlatools.com/extensions/docman/)

Answer (score 1):

By default, images/ folder can be directly accessed. Also, other common folders like media/.

Robots.txt may help to block crawlers access to index. Still, these folders will be open.

To enact a hard restriction you have to define a general access rule to block public access. For example, in htaccess, to check for Joomla session cookie.

Comment: To enact a hard restriction you have to define a general access rule to block public access. For example, in htaccess, to check for Joomla session cookie.   <> This is something where I'm interested in, coudl you point me in the right direction how to achieve this. Because this seems to me like the perfect solution, but I cannot find anything about it on Google :(